# How to create tables in sqlite without coding for Android application using xamarin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I want to develop an android  application for Hospitality POS. I am using xamarin and sqlite database. I have created a table programmatically.

My question is: how can I create a table without doing coding: like is there any way to create a table without doing coding like we use to create in SQL Server manually without doing coding.

I created the database and table using SQLite Studio, but I was unable to view those tables in my application.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Create a table without coding? What do you mean by that? You don't want to write c# to create the table? What do you mean by "like we use to create in sql server manually without doing coding"? Do you mean with a SQL Script?

Comment: yes i dont want to write c# to create the table.i wnat simple solution where i can create table manually

Answer (score 1):

If u are using xamarin and you want a portable data base take a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/ you will have to add a class in each project .Droid .IOS .Windows to get each dbPath correctly depending on platform.

To view your tables you'll have to create a class that represent those tables to get the information from db to the aplication in the link i gave up its all especified.

furthermore, In SQLite when un call SQLiteConnection.createDatabase(); you are creating the table in the dataBase file especified when creating the connection, ifnot exist, if exist and there are no errors you are just confirming that you have conection with database.  Hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

for an android app if you dont have experience, but want to implement localdb, I recomend using an ORM. Sugar ORM is really simple to use and its good. the examples on how to use it are easy to follow.

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the table with [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and then add your sqlite file to your asset folder in your Android project.

I think you then need to copy this out of there to open the database and make edits to it, something like this:

```
static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists (string dbName = "YOURDATABASENAME.sqlite")
{
  var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbName);
    if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        using (var br = new BinaryReader (Application.Context.Assets.Open (dbName)))
        {
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter (new FileStream (dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                byte [] buffer = new byte [2048];
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = br.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    bw.Write (buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```